# proof that only AND, OR operations are not adequate to construct any truth function

Tags: logic

Let E be a sentence such that it is made up of the logical propositions A and B with only ∧ and ∨ operations. No other propositions nor operators are used within E (therefore no negations). Prove that  E ↔ (~A) is not possible.

Comment: I have edited,its equivalent. I need a proof to show that not operation cant be realised using AND,OR operations.

Comment: at least give a link or proof that only AND & OR operations are not adequate for constructing any truth function.

Comment: I think I misunderstood this, I also didn't see the edit before. You cannot us ~Q? I deleted my answer due to the misunderstanding.

Comment: I just edited the question again because I was thinking more about it and finally understood the question.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question? What have you tried in order to prove this?

Comment: You might be interested in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you learned about **structural induction** on formulas? Using that you can prove:

> Let $E$ be any formula such that no connectives other than $\lor$ and $\land$ appear in it. Then its truth value under the valuation that maps every propositional variable to "true" is "true".

In particular, then, since the truth value of $\neg A$ under this valuation is "false", $E$ cannot be equivalent to $\neg A$.

If you haven't learned about structural induction, you can instead formulate the proof as being by strong induction on the number of symbols in $E$, using whatever definition of "well-formed formula" you have available.